# About heavy-duty vehicle diagnostic port

Tags: can-bus, obd, scan-tool

I am trying to design an ELD device that could be connected to the deutsche 9 pin and 6 pin port on heavy-duty vehicles. Is there any place where I can get the pinout configuration of these ports for different brands? I am looking for the pinout configuration of these trucks (Freiglighner, Kenworth, Peterbilt, International, Volvo, Mack, WesternStar).

Thank you

Comment: The workshop manuals? have you checked?

Comment: @SolarMike not available in the workshop manuals unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

Isn't it a standard, so all vehicles are wired the same (for a given connector)?

The following information comes from the [**Handbook of hardware schemes, cables layouts and connectors pinouts**](https://pinoutguide.com) website.

---

Here is the [SAE J1708 9-pin connector](https://pinoutguide.com/CarElectronics/sae_j1708_pinout.shtml).

[image]

[image]
[image]

H,J are not connected. A and B are twisted in cable. C and D are twisted in cable. F and G are twisted in cable.

SAE J1708, although still widely used, is replaced by SAE J1939 which is a CAN protocol. They both apparently use the same connector, but I don't know how you would establish which system is used.

---

Here is the [SAE J1939 9-pin connector](https://pinoutguide.com/CarElectronics/j1932_9pin_serial_pinout.shtml)

[image]

This is the connection currently in use, with the same physical 9-pin connectors.

---

Here is the [SAE J1587 6-pin connector](https://pinoutguide.com/CarElectronics/j1587_deutsch_6pin_pinout.shtml).

[image]

[image]
[image]

The 6-pin Deutsch-connector was standard from 1996 to 2001.

Comment: One small comment.  its best to verify the molded letter designation on the plastic molded hardshell connector.  Sometimes folks draw a diagram from the mating surface, but other times they draw the schematic / diagram from the back view of the connector.  I've seen it done both ways... not fun for troubleshooting.